# NOVAS for .NET

Tags: c#, astronomy

Any astronomers out there? I'm wondering if anyone has produced or stumbled upon a .NET (preferably C#) implementation of the [US Naval Observatoru Vector Astrometry Subroutines (NOVAS)](http://aa.usno.navy.mil/software/novas/novas_info.php).

Comment: Asronomer yes. Developer yes. Developing Astonomy apps no.
I'm ashamed.

Comment: When you see a scientific library that supports c and fortran, there's better than even odd that that is all that is supported... But the package seems to be in active development, why don't you ask them?

Comment: Also note the link I added may break soon. It seems that DoD wants to consolidate their web presence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know nothing (of consequence) about astronomy, and absolutely nothing about NOVAS, so please take this with a grain of salt.

But, I did look at the website, and it looks like they have a C implementation.  You could always take the C implementation, access it via pinvoke, and write a C# wrapper around it.

Comment: In fact, I am aware of something called NOVAS-COM, which is the NOVAS library with a COM wrapper around it, which is usable from .NET. What I was really interested in, though, was to see if someone had rearchitected it to be more OO.

Comment: For that kind of thing (lots of vector math and matrix multiplications involving astronomical objects) I wouldn't think being "OO" would really help much.

Comment: @Scott: There are large OO scientific packages...ROOT for one. But the OO part involves the open files, read in this, organize that, and write results parts of the work. The raw crunching still looks like plain, procedural, imperative programming.

Answer (score 1):

Are you only interested in a port of that library or anything usable from C# for astronomy?

I don't have anything for the first part, but for the second I would take a look at AGI's [Components](http://www.agi.com/products/components/). Their libraries provide ways to compute all kind of astronomical data.  The [Dynamic Geometry Library](http://www.agi.com/products/components/main.cfm?tab=overview) lets you model everything including planets and such rather easily.

Answer (score 1):

This download contains a very useful astronomical library in C#.
Sorry that I don't remember where I got it but perhaps it is documented in there somewhere.
http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=8399&lngWId=10

Sidenote: The NOVAS library is not very complete. You would be better off to pursue the SOFA lib from the International Astronomy Union. Here's the link:
http://www.iausofa.org/

Comment: +1 because SOFA looks interesting. I think whoever downvoted this answer was being a bit harsh.

Answer (score 0):

Urania is an astronomy library in C#:
http://www.smokycogs.com/blog/tutorials/astronomical-calculations-in-c-sharp/

The download is the non-obvious "here" link on the page that combines all of the sample code into a single app called Urania.

Once downloaded, you will also need to modify the Urania.sln file to fix the paths of the different libraries that he uses (MathLib, UraniaLib, etc.) and then it will compile correctly.
 (Open Urania.sld in notepad and delete: "..\Libs\" out of the 3 project paths)